# How to add the prompt to let the user select report type between crosstab and chart in Cognos

Tags: cognos

I am able to create the crosstab report and chart report separately. Our users requested us to add the prompt to the report page to switch between crosstab and chart dynamically.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step example,

- Create a value prompt (?ShowMe?) with two static choices (Chart, Crosstab)
- Make the value prompt a **radio button** group AND set it to auto submit **Yes**
- An important reminder, set a default for the value prompt (otherwise it might default to nothing)
- Select the chart on the canvas, then go to properties and find Render Variable click the ellipsis (the three dots...)
- For this example, use String variable - name it StringShowMe
- expression should be :

  ParamDisplayValue('ShowMe')
- Navigate to your variable explorer (near query explorer)
- Press the + sign to add values (in this case you will want to add Crosstab & another for Chart).  Watch out, I think this is case sensitive
- Now for the chart, go to properties, Render Variable and select StringShowMe
- Select the check box for chart
- Next select the crosstab, go to properties, Render Variable and select StringShowMe
- Select the check box for Crosstab

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via a render variable on the page or on the actual crosstab and chart object.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-hide-report-page-based-prompt for more details